# Adding a deployment to MongoDB Ops Manager

Tags: mongodb

When adding a deployment to MongoDB, it is not correctly picking up the arbiter. The replicaset consists of a primary, secondary and arbiter. I have installed the automation agent on all 3 members and the monitoring and backup agents on the primary and secondary only.

Within the Deployment page, I click on the first servers button and everything is correct.  Agents on all 3 servers are correct and present (green circle).  Additionally, the server names are all shown as the correct hostname (fqdn).  Versions of agents are consistent.

After adding the deployment, the primary and secondary nodes are picked up correctly, but the arbiter is not.  Rather, it picks up the arbiter host, but by IP address.  As such, it shows no agents at all.

From the primary and secondary members I can ping the arbiter and also connect to the arbiter using mongo --host --port.

I can't quite figure out what is wrong here and why I see all of the correct hosts in the servers section, but the deployment fails to correctly pick up the arbiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the replicaset configuration.  The rs.config members were not the same case as the resulting hostname -f return.

To fix, I updated rs.conf.  Assume the rs.conf shows Mongo-Arbiter:27017 for member[2].  For example:

hostname -f:

mongo-arbiter

cfg = rs.conf()

cfg.members[2].host="mongo-arbiter:27017"

rs.reconfig(cfg)

After ensuring all members in rs.conf matched their respective hostname, I could add the deployment to Ops Manager.